# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 - link shared to me/feed doesn't appear in Graph API Explorer

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using Android Facebook SDK 3.0 to integrate Facebook functionality with my application.

From within the application I want to share a link to Facebook. The link contains all the necessary meta-data that Facebook requires. It provides an Open-Graph object of type 'video.other' and links to a Flash player that can play the movie.

However, when I do the following in the code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("link", "http://myserver.com/opengraph?id=" + myobject.getID());
//bundle.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");
Request req = new Request(mFacebookSession, "me/feed", bundle, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
req.executeAsync();
```

the 'story' appears on the user's feed but is not accessible using the Graph API Explorer.

In response to the request, I get an object ID from Facebook (eg. 100002898114883_398866396886627) but those IDs are not valid and also can't be inspected using the Explorer.

I tried changing the destination to "me/links" but that didn't change much. Only the ID format is different and consists of only one number instead of two separated by the underscore.

I don't put any other elements in the request (picture, message, description, etc.), since they're all populated by the link as part of the metadata.